# Bluemix disconnects at publish with Paho MQTT client

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot

I am trying to run the below code I am getting EOFException. The below is my output

```
Connected to ssl://REMOVED.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:8883

.deliveryComplete() entered
Data published on topic iot-2/type/loradevice/id/cdef1234/cmd/cid/fmt/json and the msg is{"count":0,"cmd":"reset","time":"2017-01-25 18:38:34"}
connection true

Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:146)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttInputStream.readMqttWireMessage(MqttInputStream.java:65)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:107)
... 1 more
```

The code is below

```
package com.ibm.bluemixmqtt;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.commons.json.JSONException;
import org.apache.commons.json.JSONObject;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttPersistenceException;

public class AppTest2
{

    private MqttHandler1 handler;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new AppTest2().doApp();
    }

    /**
     * Run the app
     */
    public void doApp()
    {
        // Read properties from the conf file
        Properties props = MqttUtil.readProperties("Mydata\\app.conf");

        String org = "REMOVED";
        String id = "REMOVED";
        String authmethod = "REMOVED";
        String authtoken = "REMOVED";

        // isSSL property
        String sslStr = props.getProperty("isSSL");
        boolean isSSL = false;
        if (sslStr.equals("T")) {
            isSSL = true;
        }

        System.out.println("org: " + org);
        System.out.println("id: " + id);
        System.out.println("authmethod: " + authmethod);
        System.out.println("authtoken" + authtoken);
        System.out.println("isSSL: " + isSSL);

        // Format: a:<orgid>:<app-id>
        String clientId = "a:" + org + ":" + id;
        String serverHost = org + MqttUtil.SERVER_SUFFIX;

        handler = new MqttHandler1();
        handler.connect(serverHost, clientId, authmethod, authtoken, isSSL);
        publish();
    }

    public void publish(){
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        String deviceid = "cdef1234";
        try {
            jsonObj.put("cmd", "reset");
            jsonObj.put("count", 0);
            jsonObj.put("time", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        handler.publish(
                "iot-2/type/" + MqttUtil.DEFAULT_DEVICE_TYPE + "/id/" + deviceid + "/cmd/" + MqttUtil.DEFAULT_CMD_ID + "/fmt/json",
                jsonObj.toString(), false, 0);

    }
}

class MqttHandler1 implements MqttCallback
{
    private final static String DEFAULT_TCP_PORT = "1883";
    private final static String DEFAULT_SSL_PORT = "8883";

    private MqttClient client = null;

    public MqttHandler1()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable)
    {
        if (throwable != null) {
            System.out.println("Error3");
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken)
    {
        System.out.println(".deliveryComplete() entered");
    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception
    {
        String payload = new String(mqttMessage.getPayload());
        System.out.println(".messageArrived - Message received on topic " + topic + ": message is " + payload);
    }

    public void connect(String serverHost, String clientId, String authmethod, String authtoken, boolean isSSL)
    {
        // check if client is already connected
        if (!isMqttConnected()) {
            String connectionUri = null;

            // tcp://<org-id>.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:1883
            // ssl://<org-id>.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:8883
            if (isSSL) {
                connectionUri = "ssl://" + serverHost + ":" + DEFAULT_SSL_PORT;
            } else {
                connectionUri = "tcp://" + serverHost + ":" + DEFAULT_TCP_PORT;
            }

            if (client != null) {
                try {
                    client.disconnect();
                } catch (MqttException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                client = null;
            }

            try {
                client = new MqttClient(connectionUri, clientId);
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            client.setCallback(this);

            // create MqttConnectOptions and set the clean session flag
            MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
            options.setCleanSession(true);

            options.setUserName(authmethod);
            options.setPassword(authtoken.toCharArray());
            options.setKeepAliveInterval(2000);

            // If SSL is used, do not forget to use TLSv1.2
            if (isSSL) {
                java.util.Properties sslClientProps = new java.util.Properties();
                sslClientProps.setProperty("com.ibm.ssl.protocol", "TLSv1.2");
                options.setSSLProperties(sslClientProps);
            }

            try {
                // connect
                client.connect(options);
                System.out.println("Connected to " + connectionUri);
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public void disconnect()
    {

        // check if client is actually connected
        if (isMqttConnected()) {
            try {
                // disconnect
                client.disconnect();
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void subscribe(String topic, int qos)
    {

        // check if client is connected
        if (isMqttConnected()) {
            try {
                client.subscribe(topic, qos);
                System.out.println("Subscribed: " + topic);

            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            connectionLost(null);
        }
    }

    public void unsubscribe(String topic)
    {
        // check if client is connected
        if (isMqttConnected()) {
            try {

                client.unsubscribe(topic);
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            connectionLost(null);
        }
    }
    public void publish(String topic, String message, boolean retained, int qos)
    {
        // check if client is connected
        if (isMqttConnected()) {
            // create a new MqttMessage from the message string
            MqttMessage mqttMsg = new MqttMessage(message.getBytes());
            // set retained flag
            mqttMsg.setRetained(retained);
            // set quality of service
            mqttMsg.setQos(qos);
            try {
                client.publish(topic, mqttMsg);
                System.out.println("Data published on topic " + topic + " and the msg is" + mqttMsg);
                System.out.println("connection "+client.isConnected());
            } catch (MqttPersistenceException e) {
                System.out.println("Error1");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                System.out.println("Error1");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            connectionLost(null);
        }
    }

    private boolean isMqttConnected()
    {
        boolean connected = false;
        try {
            if ((client != null) && (client.isConnected())) {
                connected = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // swallowing the exception as it means the client is not connected
        }
        return connected;
    }

}
```

Any one help me on this.

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: I have edited your question to remove all of your authentication tokens. Given you have already published them to the world, I suggest you go create yourself some new tokens before someone accesses your IoT Platform organisation.

Answer (score 0):

the EOFException might indicates that the clientID is reused and the access is blocked... make sure that you only call once the connect method... possibly use only the SSL or non-SSL connection sequence